# how i can execute two threads in delphi project

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe7

My project contain two procedure that perform different tasks,
and i execute every thread in a timer.

My problem , is that ... when i run the project , and the timer start.
the thread not work fine.

**Why?**

And, can I use two threads or more in the same project?

Note: I really want to use thread, I need a solution with thread.

**This is my code without threads.**

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
i : integer;
begin
for i := 0 to 50 do
  begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i));
  sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
k : integer;
begin
for k := 0 to 50 do
  begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(k));
  sleep(500);
  end;
end;

end.
```

**With threads :**

```
type
TThread_Timer2 = class(TThread)
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

type
TThread_Timer3 = class(TThread)
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

procedure TThread_Timer2.Execute;
var
i : integer;
begin
for i := 0 to 50 do
  begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i));
  sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure TThread_Timer3.Execute;
var
k : integer;
begin
for k := 0 to 50 do
  begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(k));
  sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
thd : TThread_Timer2;
begin
  thd := TThread_Timer2.Create(true);
  try
    thd.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    thd.Priority := tpHighest;
  finally
    thd.Resume;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
trhd : TThread_Timer3;
begin
  trhd := TThread_Timer3.Create(true);
  try
    trhd.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    trhd.Priority := tpHighest;
  finally
    trhd.Resume;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Idk if it's the reason for your problem (you should elaborate on "thread not work fine") but you definitely have a problem in your code: you're updating UI from the worker thread. UI operations must happen on main thread. See `Synchronize` for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code, with correction to do UI operations only in the main thread. It's working for me:

```
TThread_Timer2 = class(TThread)
private
  FVar: Integer;

  procedure UpdateMemo;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

TThread_Timer3 = class(TThread)
private
  FVar: Integer;

  procedure UpdateMemo;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
thd : TThread_Timer2;
begin
  thd := TThread_Timer2.Create(true);
  try
    thd.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    thd.Priority := tpHighest;
  finally
    thd.Resume;
  end;
end;

procedure TThread_Timer2.Execute;
var
i : integer;
begin
for i := 0 to 50 do
  begin
  FVar := i;
  Synchronize(UpdateMemo);
  sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure TThread_Timer3.Execute;
var
k : integer;
begin
for k := 0 to 50 do
  begin
  FVar := k;
  Synchronize(UpdateMemo);
  sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
trhd : TThread_Timer3;
begin
  trhd := TThread_Timer3.Create(true);
  try
    trhd.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    trhd.Priority := tpHighest;
  finally
    trhd.Resume;
  end;

end;

procedure TThread_Timer2.UpdateMemo;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(FVar));
end;

procedure TThread_Timer3.UpdateMemo;
begin
  Form1.Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(FVar));
end;
```

I didn't change anything else in your code, but have a good read on David's answer. There are remarks there you should pay attention to.

Answer (score 8):

You can use as many threads as you like. You do however have to obey the VCL's rules. Specifically, you must only access VCL components from the main thread. Your code breaks that rule.

Whenever you want to access a VCL component from your thread, use the `TThread.Synchronize` or `TThread.Queue` method to execute code on the main thread.

Looking at your code, I'd be surprised if you really wanted to create a new thread every time a timer fires. Is that really what you intend to do? And the use of `try/finally` in the timer procedure is dubious at best. If an exception is raised do you really want to start the thread. The compiler should be telling you that the `Resume` method has been deprecated and that you should use `Start` instead. Do you have compiler hints and warnings enabled? You almost certainly do not wish to modify the thread priority. That can lead to all sorts of problems if used incorrectly, as is the case here.

---

Having said all of that, you can write your code perfectly well with timers if you wish and avoid using any threads. You need to declare a couple of counters that you increment every time the timer procedure fires. For example:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ....
  private
    FCounter1: Integer;
  .... 
  end;
```

Then when you want to start counting you initialise the counter and start the timer:

```
 FCounter1 := 0;
 Timer1.Enabled := True;
```

Whenever the timer fires your increment the counter. You stop the counter when it has reached the upper value.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(FCounter1));
  inc(FCounter1);
  if FCounter1 > 50 then
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Comment: David, your alternative code doesn't reproduces the same results: new worker threads could be created with the timer before the last one finished, and you would have them running simultaneously.

Comment: @GabrielF As I mentioned, I suspect that behaviour is not desired and should not be reproduced. The timer based code in the question does not behave that way.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got lost in the edits. There is this, however: "Note: I really want to use thread, I need a solution with thread.". I really believe the purpose of this code and question is just to learn something about using threads.

Comment: @GabrielF Maybe. But equally plausible, given all the problems with the code in the question, is that asker believes that threads are the solution because asker does not understand how to solve the problem without threads.

Comment: @David Heffernan 
I  used thread for sending email's,
I used indy component to build my project , and when i send an email my project freezing for a seconds, so that is the main problem that let me use the threads ,
Thank you alot.

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

it would be easier if you used the Parallel library. Your initial procedures would be like this:

```
proceedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);`
begin
  TTask.Run(procedure
            var 
              i: integer;
            begin
              for i:=0 to 50 do
              begin
                TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
                     procedure 
                     begin
                       Memo1.Lines.Add(i.ToString);
                       Sleep(500);
                     end);
              end;
            end);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on reply of @GabrielF I added one ttimer and make a complete code to copy and past:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

TThread_Timer2 = class(TThread)
private
  FVar: Integer;

  procedure UpdateMemo;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

TThread_Timer3 = class(TThread)
private
  FVar: Integer;

  procedure UpdateMemo;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Memo1:TMemo;
  Memo2:TMemo;
  Timer: TTimer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
thd : TThread_Timer2;
begin
  thd := TThread_Timer2.Create(true);
  try
    thd.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    thd.Priority := tpHighest;
  finally
    thd.Resume;
  end;
end;

procedure TThread_Timer2.Execute;
var
i : integer;
begin
for i := 0 to 10 do
  begin
  FVar := i;
  Synchronize(UpdateMemo);
  sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

procedure TThread_Timer3.Execute;
var
k : integer;
begin
for k := 0 to 10 do
  begin
  FVar := k;
  Synchronize(UpdateMemo);
  sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
trhd : TThread_Timer3;
begin
  trhd := TThread_Timer3.Create(true);
  try
    trhd.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    trhd.Priority := tpHighest;
  finally
    trhd.Resume;
  end;

end;

procedure TThread_Timer2.UpdateMemo;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(FVar));
end;

procedure TThread_Timer3.UpdateMemo;
begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(FVar));
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var bt1,bt2: TButton;
begin
  Form1.Width:=440;
  Form1.Height:=500;
  //
  Memo1 := TMemo.Create(nil);
  Memo1.Width := 200;
  Memo1.Height := 400;
  Memo1.Top := 30;
  Memo1.Parent := Form1;
  //
  Memo2 := TMemo.Create(nil);
  Memo2.Width := 200;
  Memo2.Height := 400;
  Memo2.Top := 30;
  Memo2.Left := 210;
  Memo2.Parent := Form1;
  //
  Timer := TTimer.Create(nil);
  Timer.Interval := 10000;
  Timer.OnTimer := Timer2Timer;
  Timer.Enabled := true;
  //
  bt1 := TButton.Create(nil);
  bt1.Width := 200;
  bt1.OnClick := Timer1Timer;
  bt1.Caption := 'Create thread Memo1';
  bt1.Parent := Form1;
  //
  bt2 := TButton.Create(nil);
  bt2.Left:=210;
  bt2.Width := 200;
  bt2.OnClick := Timer2Timer;
  bt2.Caption := 'Create thread Memo2';
  bt2.Parent := Form1;

end;

end.
```

Maybe it helps someone. I wrote and tested it on Delphi7.